# Running jupyter notebook throws an error when run using google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a jupyter notebook that uses plotly.py to make some interactive plots.  It runs just as I expect.  However, when I use the same notebook in Google Colaboratory I get an error message.  The message is : "ValueError: All arguments should have the same length.".  I cannot figure out why I get an error on one platform(Colab) but not any other.  Is there some thing I should do to get the notebook to work on Colab?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the relevant code and the traceback (if any).

Comment: I would be happy to post the code but it is long.  I am not sure why the code works on juypter notebooks but not colab.

Comment: How can I add to my above question, that is, how do I add in the code?